# ArrayList to File and back

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I need professional help, I am trying to make this ListView work. I made ArrayList where I put HashMap to fill ListView using SimpleAdapter. I am using constructor to put new score and write it to file, normally, I start activity using Intent.

```
    public class ScoreList extends ListActivity {

    private static final String SCORE = "score";
private static final String NAME = "name";
public String name;
public int score;
ArrayList map_list;
HashMap<String, String> map;
private Context c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
    map_list = new ArrayList();

    try {
        map_list = read(c);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put(NAME, NAME);
    map.put(SCORE, SCORE);
    map_list.add(map);
    String[] from = {NAME,SCORE};
    int[] to = {R.id.nameRow,R.id.scoreRow};
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ScoreList.this, map_list, R.layout.row_style, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

    public ScoreList() {}

    public ScoreList(Context c,String name,int score) {
this.c=c;
this.score = score;
this.name = name;

map_list = new ArrayList();

try {

    map_list = read(c);

} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put(NAME, name);
map.put(SCORE, String.valueOf(score));
map_list.add(map);

Log.d("map_list", map_list.toString());

try {
    write(c,map_list);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

   public void write(Context c,ArrayList  list) throws IOException {
//File file = new File("list_file");
//file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput("list_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
//Log.d("position", "write");
os.writeObject(list);
os.flush();
os.close();
  }

  public ArrayList read(Context c) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream fis;
ObjectInputStream is;
//Log.d("position", "read");
        fis = c.openFileInput("list_file");
        is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        map_list =  (ArrayList) is.readObject();
        //Log.d("input stream", String.valueOf(is.readObject()));
        is.close();
return map_list;
      } 
  }
```

Here are log messages

```
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): java.lang.NullPointerException
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at com.memorija.ScoreList.write(ScoreList.java:106)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at com.memorija.ScoreList.<init>(ScoreList.java:91)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at com.memorija.play$1$2.onClick(play.java:171)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
      05-19 18:11:55.454: E/AndroidRuntime(612): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help!

Comment: `public ScoreList() {}` . Maybe you are not initializing the variables correcty

Comment: Simple.. You don't construct any class that `extends Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not define constructors for the `Activity` class, you only override the lifecycle methods.  If you want to pass the Activity parameters, you pass them by putting extras in the `Intent`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html